# High speed photography using RPi Camera module

Tags: python, camera, raspicam

I'm trying to capture high speed water flow movement in a small dark chamber with a cool white 5 W high power LED as a flasher. My target is to achieve quick exposure using 0.8 millisecond light pulse. Then quick movement of water can be seen without blurring.

I'm using RPi 3 with Camera module 1.3 version and picamera python library.

I could get non-blurred images. But those pictures have color imbalances. Under some settings pictures get darker. Another important thing is I want a frame rate > 20. Can someone please help me to figure out best picamera settings for my requirement. Followings show my best attempts (code) and observations (images).

**Attempt 1**

```
import time
import picamera
with picamera.PiCamera(sensor_mode=7) as camera:

    time.sleep(2)

    camera.iso = 800
    camera.shutter_speed = 150000
    print (camera.exposure_speed)
    # output >>> 16498
    camera.awb_mode = 'off'
    camera.awb_gains = (8, 8)
    camera.exposure_mode = 'off'

    camera.capture_sequence((
        'frames/image%03d.jpg' % i
        for i in range(120)
        ), use_video_port=True)
```

[image: Attempt 1 output]

**Attempt 2**

```
import time
import picamera
with picamera.PiCamera(sensor_mode=7) as camera:

    time.sleep(2)

    camera.iso = 800
    camera.shutter_speed = 150000
    print (camera.exposure_speed)
    # output >>> 16498

    camera.capture_sequence((
        'frames/image%03d.jpg' % i
        for i in range(120)
        ), use_video_port=True)
```

[image: Attempt 2 output]